# How do I get the sum?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum

I don´t know where I should put some () to get the sum.
Or canI do it it in some better way? :)

```
SELECT COUNT (CAST(Value as int)) FROM [tblExtraFieldData],[tblTask]
WHERE [tblExtraFieldData].[FieldId] = '10010' 
AND [tblExtraFieldData].[OwnerId]=[tblTask].[Id] 
AND [tblTask].[Status]=0
AND [tblExtraFieldData].[Value]>'1'
AND [tblTask].[ProjectNr]= 'Offert - Bygg'

-

SELECT COUNT (CAST(Value as int)) FROM [tblExtraFieldData],[tblTask]
WHERE [tblExtraFieldData].[FieldId] = '10010' 
AND [tblExtraFieldData].[OwnerId]=[tblTask].[Id] 
AND [tblTask].[Status]=0
AND [tblTask].[ProjectNr]= 'Offert - Bygg'
```

Comment: SUM of what? Describe your problem.

Comment: If possible write your sample data and expect output you want

Comment: Anyway, I guess you miss a GROUP BY somewhere...

Comment: @skypjack, depends on if the SUM of all rows is supposed to be returned (1 row result), or SUM's for differents groups (multi-row result.)

Comment: Added `sql-server` and `tsql` tags based on the non-standard syntax

Comment: Indeed it makes sense, it depends on if he wants to COUNT or to SUM.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
select sum(b.a) from(
SELECT COUNT (CAST(Value as int)) as a FROM [tblExtraFieldData],[tblTask]
WHERE [tblExtraFieldData].[FieldId] = '10010' 
AND [tblExtraFieldData].[OwnerId]=[tblTask].[Id] 
AND [tblTask].[Status]=0
AND [tblExtraFieldData].[Value]>'1'
AND [tblTask].[ProjectNr]= 'Offert - Bygg'

union all

SELECT COUNT (CAST(Value as int)) as a FROM [tblExtraFieldData],[tblTask]
WHERE [tblExtraFieldData].[FieldId] = '10010' 
AND [tblExtraFieldData].[OwnerId]=[tblTask].[Id] 
AND [tblTask].[Status]=0
AND [tblTask].[ProjectNr]= 'Offert - Bygg') b
```

Comment: The first section before - is 18 and the other section i 24 and it should be 4. Now it turns into 36...